# Laravel Inject a custom singleton service

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

I have a custom singleton service and instantiate it using `App::make('SingletonService')`. Now, I have another service, and I want to inject the singleton into it. Inside the service provider of my secondary service, I tried:

```
$this->app['UserHelper'] = $this->app->share(function(){
    return new UserHelper(App::get('SingletonService'), new User);
});
```

But the `__constructor` of my singleton is called again! My singleton service provider is:

```
$this->app->bindShared('SingletonService', function() { 
    return new SingletonService();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your implementation of the Singleton pattern? Generally singleton patterns involve a static method for fetching the singleton itself. Something like `SingletonService::getInstance()`.

Comment: @Scopey, I thought Laravel will take care of that for you, hence their singleton make. My method does not have a `getInstance()`. There is a constructor that sets everything up. All of my class has static variables/methods.

Comment: @Scopey, also, if I am using a `getInstance` that means I need a private `__constructor`. How do I then inject my dependecies into that?